# drawing epoxides, the 3d shape

Tags: organic-chemistry, conformers

given the image on the left, when you look at it from the side would it look like the image in the right? since the thicker lines means it's coming out of the page?

[image]

Comment: The oxygen will be going down: try and get access to Avogadro (I'd recommend installing it on your laptop) and draw the molecule.  A bit of googling gave this page, https://www.rollapp.com/app/avogadro it means you can draw the molecule and manipulate it without having to download the software.

Answer (score 5):

From [PubChem](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Cyclopentene_oxide#section=3D-Conformer)

[image]
[image]

So the molecule is sort of boat shaped.

Comment: the first illustration I drew is from the textbook. How does that illustration reconcile with the 3d shape you created?

Comment: Think of the chair and boat forms of cyclohexane. In this case the boat form would seem to be the more stable. I don't know what the ratio of the two forms is, but the ratio is surely a function of temperature.

Comment: The oxygen bridge strains the C-C bond. The "boat" form has the two hydrogens on the carbons with the bridged oxygen pointing away from each other. If the oxygen end were flipped into the "chair" position then the two hydrogens would be much closer together.

Answer (score 2):

If I use chemapp and draw the structure of cyclopentane-1,2-epoxide, it looks like this:

[image]

You can see that the the epoxide group is kinda tilted upwards. This is perfectly understandable, since a *trans* geometry is unacceptable.

Comment: @Fl.pf. Thanks for pointing it out, its fixed now.

Comment: And thus, I shall remove my downvote